# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch when setting an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in VideosController#update
Topic(#2173382840) expected, got String(#2148246520)
```

It's from this method:

```
def assign_topics
    if @topic_names
      self.topics = @topic_names.each do |name|
        Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
     end
    end
  end
```

What is this error saying? I don't understand there being a type "topic" when topic is a model for me...

Comment: What it's saying is "I wanted a Topic, but you gave me a String!". @coder_tim's answer tells you why it's saying that, and what you should do to fix it.

Comment: @Phrogz - thanks for the details, I should have mentioned that in my answer

Comment: yeah but I think what Phrogz said is self-evident...I was more concerned with why, and that's what you answered @coder_tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"each" returns the original array or enumerable, try using "map" instead